# How to sum multiple columns with Group by in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `tblEmployee`. I would like sum the value and grouped by `UserId`.

tblEmployee:

```
+--------+----------+-------+
| UserId | UserName | Value |
+--------+----------+-------+
|      1 |    A     |   100 |
|      1 |    B     |   200 |
|      1 |    C     |   300 |
|      2 |    D     |   100 |
|      3 |    E     |   200 |
|      3 |    F     |   300 |
+--------+----------+-------+
```

I would like sum the value based on `userid` and shows like below output.

Output:

```
    +--------+----------+-------+---------+
    | UserId | UserName | Value | Result  |
    +--------+----------+-------+---------+
    |      1 |    A     |   100 |         |
    |      1 |    B     |   200 |  600    |
    |      1 |    C     |   300 |         |
    |      2 |    D     |   100 |  100    |
    |      3 |    E     |   200 |         |
    |      3 |    F     |   300 |  500    |
    +--------+----------+-------+---------+
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

```
select 
userid,username,
value,
sum(value) over (partition by userid) as totalval
from table
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use a partition, you can also use a subquery with `GROUP BY` to get the output you want:

```
SELECT t1.UserId, t1.UserName, t1.Value, t2.Result
FROM tblEmployee t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT UserId, SUM(Value) AS Result
    FROM tblEmployee
    GROUP BY UserId
) t2
ON t1.UserId = t2.UserId
```

Comment: This works when `tblEmployee.UserId`  column doesn't include `NULL`s.